# Jolt Transformation - Replace all single quotes to double quotes in string

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I would like to replace all " ' "  with " '' " in a string

```
{
    "name": "test ' string ' one"    
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{
    "name": "test '' string '' one"    
}
```

is there a function replace( " ' " , " '' ")  ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no such function but simulate splitting by single quotes through use of `"*'*'*"` qualifier as in the following case

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*'*'*": { "$1": "&(1,1)''&(1,2)''&(1,3)" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "@0"
      }
    }
  }
]
```